# Install git Plugin for DBeaver

Tags: windows, installation, eclipse, jar, dbeaver

**Problem**

I have `DBeaver 6.3.3` installed on one of our remote servers. This remote server has no connection to the internet. Thus, I need to install drivers / plugins from a local file (I have the possibility to copy files to a drive which is accessible from the remote server).

I was able to install the MS SQL driver and I can connect to the MS SQL database.

However, I struggle to install the git plugin. I went to https://dbeaver.io/update/git/latest downloaded all files from there and added this folder here:

[image: Add repository in DBeaver]

Everything seems to work fine, for I see the git plugin the selection area:

[image: Selection Area]

However, when I try to install it, I get an error message about a missing dependency:

> ```
> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.   
> Software being installed: DBeaver Git support
> 1.0.13.202001191557 (org.jkiss.dbeaver.git.feature.feature.group 1.0.13.202001191557)   Missing requirement: JGit SSH support based on Apache MINA sshd 5.6.0.201912101111-r (org.eclipse.jgit.ssh.apache
> 5.6.0.201912101111-r) requires 'java.package; net.i2p.crypto.eddsa [0.3.0,0.4.0)' but it could not be found   
>
> Cannot satisfy dependency:
> From: DBeaver Git support 1.0.13.202001191557 (org.jkiss.dbeaver.git.feature.feature.group 1.0.13.202001191557)
> To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.jgit.ssh.apache [5.6.0.201912101111-r,5.6.0.201912101111-r]
> ```

I tried to download the corresponding jar from https://javalibs.com/artifact/net.i2p.crypto/eddsa and tried to place this ja in the `plugin` folder of DBeaver but I still get the same error message.

**Question**

How can I install the Git Plugin without connection to the internet properly?